# Flutter Inspector is showing in a weird way

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am using Android Studio with flutter but flutter inspector has a problem which I couldn't fix in anyway.

It is showing not in a right way. I deleted Android Studio and installed again and it didn't help with the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the resolution of your windows display; the resolution or pixel breaking issue of Flutter Inspector will get resolved.

Answer (score 1):

This will also work

```
File => Settings => Languages & Frameworks => Flutter => Experiments => Unselect 'Enable embedding DevTools in the Flutter Inspector tool window' => Apply => OK => Restart Android Studio for changes to take effect.
```

From [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/5104#issuecomment-764322821)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is already filed as a bug. Could you contribute there and help them fix the bug?

https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/5019

Answer (score 0):

The problem was about Display settings of my windows. On the scale part it was  "change the size of texts apps and other items by 125% " When I changed it to 100% it is fixed :) Thank you for the answer